# If $f(x)$ is continuous on $D = [a,b] $ where $0<b-a< \infty$, then is $f[a,b] = [f(a),f(b)]$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)$ is continuous on $D =  [a,b] $ where $0<b-a< \infty$, then is $f[a,b] = [f(a),f(b)]$?

Here's my attempt:

Yes, $f[a,b] = [f(a),f(b)]$

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $0<b-a< \infty$, then this implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$, then this implies that $D$ is compact.

If $f$ is continuous on a compact domain, then $rng[f]$ is also compact.

Thus $f[a,b] = [f(a),f(b)]$

Is my logic correct? I feel like I'm over-simplifying.

Comment: Consider $f : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = -x$.

Comment: The answers that are given are good. I wanted to add that a function being uniformly continuous on its domain does not imply that the domain is compact. For instance, $f(x)=x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, but this does not mean that $(0,1)$ is compact.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = 1$

Answer (score 5):

No. Consider $f = \sin, [a,b] = [0,\pi]$.

All of your logic is correct except for the line $f[a,b] = [f(a),f(b)]$. This only happens if $f$ is monotone.

Edit: As Alex S. pointed out, "If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$, then this implies that $D$ is compact." does not hold.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is closed, $f[a,b]$ is closed.  By IVT,  $f[a,b]$ takes on any values between maximum and minimum of $f$. So 
$$
f[a,b] =[\inf\limits_{x\in[a,b]}{f(x)},\sup\limits_{x\in[a,b]}{f(x)}]
$$
If $f$ is monotone, then 
$$
\inf\limits_{x\in[a,b]}{f(x)}=f(a)\quad\text{and }\quad\sup\limits_{x\in[a,b]}{f(x)}]=f(b)
$$
So $f[a,b]=[f(a), f(b)]$.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider any continuous non-constant function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$  with $f(a)=f(b)$.